# How do I make the ball rotate?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to implement a game where you have to push a ball around through rings on a table and I want my ball to rotate but can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I read about sprite sheets but I don't know if that would give me a smooth appearance. I haven't tried implementing it just want to confirm if that would be a good idea as I don't want all that time to get wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an Animation:

```
Animation rotation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
rotation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotation.setDuration(2000);

ballView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add :

```
private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
```

and initialize it :

```
rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(1500);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

then start the animation whenever you like  :

```
YOUR_IMAGE.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: my pleasure :) hope it helps :)